# Configure JMS topic in Jboss

Tags: jboss, jms, wildfly

I have configured JBOSS_EAP_7.0 for jms topic. In jboss admin console, i can not view any sent messages. But for jms queue connection even without any consumer i can view sent items. What is the reason that i can not view any messages and in jms topic how to verify that message was sent to topic.

This is my producer class

```
@Stateless
public class ClientSenderFacadeBean {


    private static final OMSLogHandlerI logger = new Log4j2Handler("ClientSenderFacadeBean");
    @Resource(lookup = "java:/JmsXA")     // inject ConnectionFactory (more)
    protected ConnectionFactory  factory;


    @Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/topic/ORD_CLINT_PUSH")
    protected Topic target;

    private Connection  connection = null;
    private Session session = null;



    public void sendMessage(String message) {

        MessageProducer producer= null;
        try {
            if(connection==null){  //todo verify
                connection = factory.createConnection();
            }
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            producer = session.createProducer(target);
            producer.setDisableMessageID(true);
            TextMessage outmsg = session.createTextMessage(message);
            producer.send(outmsg);
            logger.info("Message was sent to Topic");
            producer.setTimeToLive(900000);//15min  //todo
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(" Error when sending order to jboss:", e);
            throw new OMSCoreRuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (producer != null)
                    producer.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.warn("\n jms producer close error:",e);
            }
            try {
                if (session != null)
                    session.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.warn("\n jms session close error:",e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't see the messages because a topic with zero subscribers never has any messages to send

Comment: Will T thanks for your reply

Comment: One option is create durable subscriber for topic, attach it to topic once. after this, every copy of sent message will be preserve on topic for durable subscriber until you unsubscribe it.

Comment: Thank you Varsha i did create durable subscriber. But when subscriber disconnect, Jboss keeps subscribers session for some amount of time (connection ttl). In that period if i send some messages, those will mark as delivered count which means message is pushed to subscriber but yet to acknowledge it. As soon as i reconnect to server those delivered messages are missing.